# Retrieve all selected checkboxes in an array with each id name, and pass it to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a series of checkboxes as such:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox35080"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox23000"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5000"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox7000"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox65354"></td>
```

where they can be all checked or not at the same time, as some one can be checked and others not.

What I need to do is retrieve all the checked checkboxes in jQuery or Javascript, store their sub-string number as elements in an array, and pass this array to PHP.

So I wrote this short example of code in order to print the PHP array when I pass it from jQuery :

**jQuery code**

```
function foo()
{
   var $substr = "checkbox";
   var $id = "";
   var $checkedBoxes = new Array();

   $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function()
   { 
      $id = $(this).attr('id');
      checkedBoxes.push($id.substring($substr.length));
   });

   $("#content").load("file.php", {checkboxes: $checkedBoxes});
}
```

**PHP code** in **file.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["checkboxes"]))
{
   $checkboxes = json_decode($_POST["checkboxes"], true);
   print_r($checkboxes);
}
?>
```

But I can't see the array printed on output.
I also tried using **$_REQUEST** & **$_GET** methods. No way, and I don't know what I am doing wrong (I don't think jQuery is my best).

How can I achieve this task? What's wrong in my code?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/707ek35u/

Comment: Instead of using jQuery to generate the array, why not just use `<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox7000" name="checkbox[7000]">` for example? the `[]` in the name will make it a array. - FYI input's are found / identified by their name, not the ID.

Comment: @Epodax, my idea too, or use a data-attribute: `data-id="7000"`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jQuery to do this, you could simply use HTML / php as it's fully cable of achieving what you desire. Just add the `[]` to the name and it will be generated as an' array. Like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox7000" name="checkboxes[7000]"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox35080" name="checkboxes[35080]"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox23000" name="checkboxes[23000]></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5000" name="checkboxes[5000]"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox7000" name="checkboxes[7000]"></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox65354" name="checkboxes[65354]"></td>
```

This way you can avoid having to do it with jQuery. Also, just as a reminder, values from a form are fetched by `name=""` and not `id=""`

Comment: Hi! Is it correct, in jQuery, to get this array as: `var $checkedBoxes = $("[name='checkboxes']");` ?

Comment: Try, if it works yes, if not, then no :) I'm not that good in jQuery myself, but again, the point with my answer was that you could avoid using jQuery all together to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code did not worked is due to wrong selector to target checked element. they do not have name attribute equals to type.

also you have defined array name as `$checkedBoxes`. however you are using variable `checkedBoxes` in each loop. you need to use:

```
var $substr = "checkbox";
var $id = "";
var $checkedBoxes = new Array();
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){ 
   $id = $(this).attr('id');
   $checkedBoxes.push($id.substring($substr.length));
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cb4rvpba/)**

However you can narrow down your code by using jquery `.map()` function:

```
var $checkedBoxes =  $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function()   { 
  return this.id.substring($substr.length);
}).get();
```

**[Working Demo with `.map()`](https://jsfiddle.net/pLzu1nhz/)**

Comment: Hi!, I understang your explanation, thank you. However, I still cannot print out the array in PHP. :(

Comment: @simo-zz: why not. arrays are supported in both client and server side.

Comment: It seems the condition `if(isset($_POST["checkboxes"]))` is not executed. Maybe the code `$("#content").load("file.php", {checkboxes: $checkedBoxes});` is not the right way to pass the array to PHP.. I still don't know..

Comment: you can debug the php script in file.php which is accepting this array as parameter.

Comment: It's does not work. It's like the condition is neither executed. I wrote a `var_dump($checkboxes);`, also a simple `echo "XXXXX";`, but nothing happens. I suppose the problem is in the jquery code.

Comment: @simo-zz: definitely not in jquery code. check the value of `$checkedBoxes` before load method.

Answer (score 0):

I post the solution:

**HTML code**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxPort[]" value="1000">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxPort[]" value="1001">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxPort[]" value="1002">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxPort[]" value="1003">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxPort[]" value="1004">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxPort[]" value="1005">
```

**jQuery code**

```
function foo()
{
   var $checkedBoxes = new Array();

  $("input[name='checkboxPort[]']:checked").each(function()
  { 
    $checkedBoxes.push($(this).val());
  });

  $("#content").load("file.php", {checkboxes: $checkedBoxes});
}
```

**PHP code**

```
if(isset($_POST["checkboxes"]))
{ 
  $checkboxes = $_POST["checkboxes"];
  print_r($checkboxes)
}
```

Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Find the attached demo in fiddle

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bqskjg30/3/)</kbd>**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateTextArea() {
        var allVals = [];
        $('#mydiv :checked').each(function () {
            allVals.push($(this).val());
        });
        $('#UserRole').val(allVals);
    }
    $(function () {
        $('#mydiv input').click(updateTextArea);
        updateTextArea();
    });
});
```

Here I have taken a textarea you can save and retrieve checkboxes selection in the textarea by comma separation.